# Search for a string in file2 based on file1 and replace

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm new to the shell scripting and need your guidance regarding a typical requirement.
I have two files(1.master file and 2.pattern file)
Master file contains many fields with | delimiter and only 10th and 15th fields needs to be updated based on the pattern file.

## Master file:

```
H|20170101

123|field2|field3|...|field10|field11...|field15|....|field150

...

...

T|1000000
```

## Pattern file:

```
Europe|EU

Australia|AU

China|CN
```

For example,

```
123|1|2|3|...|9|nice weather in europe today|11|.....
```

the above line need to be replaced into

```
123|1|2|3|...|9|nice weather in EU today|11|.....
```

I began with a simple sed command by replacing the master file by getting value from pattern file .. But it's incomplete as im not sure how to process a huge master file
and that too replacing specific fields.

```
while read line

do

value1=$(echo $line | awk -F"|" '{print $1}')

value2=$(echo $line | awk -F"|" '{print $2}')

sed -i 's/ '${value1}' /'${value2}'/g' master.txt

done < pattern.txt
```

Above script is very slow for a 10mb file where as my Master file is bit huge (100 mb).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one shot in the dark as your sample data didn't even have 10 fields and I didn't have time to create test sets. Hope it works, using awk. Next time, please be considerate enough to create working data sets (enough fields, `Europe` =/= `europe`, etc). LIke I said, untested:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }                      # delimiters
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }                # read patterns and hash them
{
    for(i=10;i<=NF;i+=5)                  # iterate every fifth field
        if(i%10==0||i%15==0){             # pick only mod 10 and mod 15
            n=split($i,b," ")             # split to b the chosen ones
            for(j=1;j<=n;j++)             # iterate thru the chosen ones
                if(b[j] in a)             # if word is found among patterns
                    sub(b[j],a[b[j]],$i)  # switch the matching pattern
        }
}1' pattern master
```

Comment: Are we confident that the pattern alternates are not too large to fit into the associative array?

Comment: @cdarke Nope, but a 100 MB for the master. Pfft. We are daring,

Comment: @cdarke I hash the pattern file and iterate thru the master. I think it's good.

Comment: I was developing a similar solution but i got late... Maybe you can jump directly to field10 and field15 instead of iterating every 5 fields?

Comment: @james, is it possible to make it case insensitive. I tried with IGNORECASE=1 but no luck..

Comment: Use `tolower()` with `$1` and `b[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

The script is *probably* slow because of the number child processes you are creating.  Also, you are reading the larger file (`master.txt`) more times than the smaller one.

Note that the `-i` option to `sed` is non-standard.

You can get rid of the calls to the `awk` language interpreter and the `sed` editor by using `bash`:

```
# Read patterns into an associative array
# Requites Bash 4 or later
declare -A patterns

while IFS='|' read key value
do
    patterns[$key]="$value"

done < pattern.txt 

# Set the option for case insensitive patterns
shopt -s nocasematch

while read line
do
    # Iterate through the patterns array
    for key in "${!patterns[@]}"
    do 
        line="${line//$key/${patterns[$key]}}"
    done  

    echo "$line"

done < master.txt
```

That does not allow only certain fields to be edited.  This does:

```
# Read patterns into an associative array
# Requites Bash 4 or later
declare -A patterns

while IFS='|' read key value
do
    patterns[$key]="$value"

done < pattern.txt

# Set the option for case insensitive patterns
shopt -s nocasematch

# IFS is set here because localised setting for 'echo' does not work in bash
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS='|'

# "line" is an array
while read -a line
do
    # Check there are at least 15 fields
    if (( ${#line[@]} >= 15 ))
    then
        # Iterate through the patterns array
        for key in "${!patterns[@]}"
        do
            # We are only interested in the 10th and 15th fields
            # (index 9 and 14 since arrays index from zero)
            val="${line[9]}"
            line[9]="${val//$key/${patterns[$key]}}"
            val="${line[14]}"
            line[14]="${val//$key/${patterns[$key]}}"
        done
    fi
    echo "${line[*]}"

done < master.txt

IFS="$oldIFS"
```

Comment: This will replace EUROPE with EU in any field and not field10 or field15 as OP describes.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou:  my script just replaces the `awk`and `sed`.  It acts in the same way as the OP's  script.  But you are right, I have not separated out the required fields.  That will take a few more lines and I'll look at that tomorrow.

Comment: In any case if OP is happy with sed , then your script will also make him happy. Maybe this needs to be clarified by OP. By the way i think you can improve performance of your solution by avoiding pattern file open/close for every line of the huge master file. You might consider to read patterns at the beginning, store contents  in an array maybe and iterate through the array when reading the master file.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou:  I was reluctant to use an associative array because I had no idea how large it would be.  However the OP has accepted the `awk` solution so I guess it cannot be that large.  Will update.

Comment: Final bash-only solution supplied.  Generally `awk` I/O is quicker than bash I/O, so the `awk` solution will probably perform better, but it was an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sed alternative proposal, based on the fact that sed can read commands from a file.

First i create a sed command file using the contents of your pattern file:

```
$ cat file1
europe|EU
australia|AU
china|CN

$ while IFS="|" read -r a b;do 
> echo -e "s/((.[^|]*.){9})(.+)\<$a\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3$b\4\5/g";
> echo -e "s/((.[^|]*.){14})(.+)\<$a\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3$b\4\5/g";
> done<file1 >file11

$ cat file11
s/((.[^|]*.){9})(.+)\<europe\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3EU\4\5/g
s/((.[^|]*.){14})(.+)\<europe\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3EU\4\5/g
s/((.[^|]*.){9})(.+)\<australia\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3AU\4\5/g
s/((.[^|]*.){14})(.+)\<australia\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3AU\4\5/g
s/((.[^|]*.){9})(.+)\<china\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3CN\4\5/g
s/((.[^|]*.){14})(.+)\<china\>([^|]+)(.*)/\1\3CN\4\5/g
```

Then the only thing we have to do is to call sed and feed sed with above commands file11.

```
$ cat file2
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in europe today|11|12|europe|14|nice weather in europe today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice european weather today|11|12|europe|14|nice european weather today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in china today|11|12|china|14|nice weather in china today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in china today|11|12|china|14|best of chinas today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in australia today|11|12|australia|14|nice weather in australia today|16
```

I have fullfilled file2 with various values for testing and to be sure that the sed regex provided will replace 10th and 15th field only , and only when we have a literal word match (i.e word `europe` is replaced by `EU` but word  `european` is not replaced)

These are the results which seems to be pretty good. I expect this sed solution to be really fast with your big file.

```
$ sed -E -f file11 file2
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in EU today|11|12|europe|14|nice weather in EU today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice european weather today|11|12|europe|14|nice european weather today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in CN today|11|12|china|14|nice weather in CN today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in CN today|11|12|china|14|best of chinas today|16
1|2|3|4|5|europe|7|8|9|nice weather in AU today|11|12|australia|14|nice weather in AU today|16
```

Comment: @cdarke I deleted previous awk solution and i built a sed solution after a lot of testing. What do you think of this sed...? I enjoyed builting this!

Comment: I can see where you went with this, I must admit that I would not have thought of that approach.  I think we (you and I) got far more from this question than the OP did :-)

Comment: @cdarke Thanks man. Even your approach is very good. For sure we went a lot of steps ahead OP question, but we both did that for a reason: it was fun! Moreover we both get some benefit from each other answer !

Comment: That's why I'm here!

Comment: @Vensmira With respect to the fact that you have already choose the best solution for you, do you mind to give a try to my solution? I am curious to see how it performs on your big-real file.  Tip: You can "measure" the time required for each solution (kind of benchmark) by using "time" tool in front of the command (i.e `$ time awk 'code here'`) `time` will report to you the time required for the command to complete.